# Struct Confusion in C

Tags: c, struct, typedef

So I was looking through [this C tutorial](http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex19.html) and I found these lines of code:

```
struct Monster {
    Object proto;
    int hit_points;
};
typedef struct Monster Monster;
```

And I thought that it would make much more sense if it were like this:

```
typedef struct {
    Object proto;
    int hit_points;
} Monster;
```

I could could be totally wrong, because I am very new to C, but I would assume both these pieces of code would do the same thing. So is they do, then is there any reason to prefer one over the other? Or if they are different, what makes them different? Thanks!

Comment: I think your answer lies in looking at the definition of the `Room` structure on the same page. You cannot have a recursive `typedef`, so only the method chosen works. But typically I prefer the second method for the non-recursive struct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are times when the second form won't work. Say you want to create a linked list of `Monster`s. With the first form, you can add a pointer to the next `Monster` in the `struct`.

```
struct Monster {
    Object proto;
    int hit_points;
    struct Monster* next;
};
```

You can't do that in the second form since the `struct` doesn't have a name.

Answer (score 3):

The first piece of code defines a type `struct Monster`, and then gives it another name `Monster`.

The second piece of code defines structure with no tag, and typedef it as `Monster`.

With either code, you can use `Monster` as the type. But only in the first code, you can also use `struct Monster`.

Comment: dear yuhao, is there a difference between type and class declaration in C? how would you instantiate object classes in both instances?

Comment: @laycat There's no class in C, are you thinking about C++?

Answer (score 0):

The definitions (from the first part of the question - plus my liberal re-formating):

```
struct Monster
   {
   Object proto;
   int hit_points;
   };

typedef struct Monster Monster;
```

Is equivalent to:

```
typedef struct Monster
   {
   Object proto;
   int hit_points;
   } Monster;
```

My preference is:

```
typedef struct MONSTER_S
   {
   Object proto;
   int hit_points;
   } MONSTER_T;
```

FYI... a struct name isn't required.  So if the code only needs to use the type, the following is also fine:

```
typedef struct
   {
   Object proto;
   int hit_points;
   } MONSTER_T;
```